# Left operand of + is a garbage value

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am receiving the following warning in a class extending UIView and have no idea why:

[image]

Also, does anyone know what those blue arrows are suppose to represent?

It is initialised using the following function:

```
- (void)updateIndicators {
    if (indicator) {
        [indicator removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if (mode == MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate) {
        self.indicator = [[[MBRoundProgressView alloc] initWithDefaultSize] autorelease];
    }
    else if (mode == MBProgressHUDModeCustomView && self.customView != nil){
        self.indicator = self.customView;
    } else {
        self.indicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                           initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];
        [(UIActivityIndicatorView *)indicator startAnimating];
    }


    [self addSubview:indicator];
}
```

Comment: what is the bast class your class is extending?

Comment: The blue arrows represent the program flow that will result in the error it is highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `indicator` isn't yet part of the view hierarchy, then its `bounds` property is going to be useless.

Try this instead...

```
CGRect indicatorFrame = indicator.frame;
self.width = indicatorFrame.size.width + 2 * margin;
self.height = indicatorFrame.size.width + 2 * margin;
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but that doesn't fix the warning

Comment: What type of object is `indicator` and how is it being initialized?

Comment: `indicator` is a `UIView`. It appears that `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` or `- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view` initiate it after a series of functions, but another way of calling init that doesn't initiate it at all

Comment: nm, I not convinced that this issue is worth worrying about